# Which word to use when speaker sound is not working properly

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds

I have a malfunctioned speaker, its sound does not come out normally but is like being stuck, which word(s) could I use to describe a speaker with defected sound? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be tempted to describe the sound the speaker makes. There are lots of ways a speaker could be broken, The sound could be:

- tinny
- cracked
- distorted
- warped
- garbled

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

- *[choppy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/choppy#Adjective)*, “Discontinuous, intermittent. [eg] *The sound is choppy in this video*”
- *[staticky](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/staticky)*, “Resembling or containing static [eg] *The connection was staticky*”
- *[buzzing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/buzzing#Noun)*, “The sound produced by something that buzzes [eg] *I can hear buzzing coming from the television*”

Three possibly-relevant ELU questions are  [Can sound be "blurry?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/23955),  [What word can I use for unclear music?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/67933), and [Term for buzzing or hissing sound often created by vibration](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/56439).  In an answer to that last, I wrote:

> An [webervst.com spterm.html](http://www.webervst.com/spterm.html) webpage defines numerous terms for speaker-related distortions, including *Boomy, Breakup, Buzz, Rattle, Cone Cry, Ghost Notes, Edge Yowl, Crunch, Damping, Diffused, Fizz, Flabbing, Farting Out, Harsh, Honking, Muddy, Peaky, Presence Notch, Voice Coil Rub*. The web page attributes buzz and rattle to speaker damage, caused for example by exceeding a speaker's power limits.

Answer (score 0):

> **Clipping**- a form of distortion caused by cutting off the peaks of audio signals. Clipping usually occurs in the amplifier when it's input
>   signal is too large or when the voltage rails of the power supply
>   cannot deliver the necessary voltage to the power amp.
>
> **Distortion** - any undesirable change or error in the reproduction of
>   sound that alters the original signal.
>
> **Phase Distortion** - a type of audible distortion caused by time delay between various parts of the signal; can be caused by equalizer

http://www.audioholics.com/how-to-shop/audio-terms-and-definitions

Answer (score -1):

You can use *faulty speaker* or *defective speaker*, for example.

Comment: Faulty and defective are words with wider meanings. But here we're only concern with sound of speaker nothing else. @superluminary has the correct answer, he described the problems in sound.